# AWS Wordpress site accessible using both domain and public IP. How to disable?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My wordpress site is accessible from both the IP address and the domain name.
https://example.com and IP

How to redirect IP address to domain name?

The IP address is also indexed on Google.

Installed using Bitnami marketplace on AWS

Answer (score 0):

It seems this have been discussed on bitnami community: https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-to-block-access-ip/61773

Credits to user [Jota (Bitnami Engineer)](https://community.bitnami.com/u/jota):

> You need to made 3 changes in the solution to make it work with the
> domain only:
>
> Change the WordPress configuration file to use your domain
> https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/configure-domain/
>
> Change the WP database to use that domain
> https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/update-ip-hostname/ (*)
>
> Change Apache to redirect all the requests to your domain
> https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/use-single-domain/

(*) This link do not work right now. But this topic is discussed here:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/only-use-dns-name-for-the-website-rather-its-ip-address-for-security/85944